# How to infer a given (EPSG) projection property: is it area-, scale- or distance-preserving?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

Imagine you are given a `EPSG:abcd` crs code, and would like to know the properties of that crs, i.e. you want to know whether it is area-, distance-, scale-preserving etc.

Are there tools (ideally in R) that allow you to infer the property of an arbitrary `EPSG:abcd` projection (or its wkt definition)? Currently I will just search the crs code on [www.epsg.io](http://www.epsg.io), and use some guessing to find out what is the property of the projection. Are there more formal approaches available, and tools developed for that?

Alternatively, could I create polygons in long-lat, compute their area/distances etc using spherical geometry (S2), and then compare to the results obtained after projection using planar geometry? Would that be a valid approach to infer its property?

Test case: what is the property of [EPSG:3118](https://epsg.io/3118), is it area- or distance-preserving etc?

Comment: Not sure there is a formal answer to this. The key item as far as I understand it is the Projection type found in each CRS definition (+extent to give where approximations can be made). 3118 is Transverse Mercator and therefore conformal. To your idea of assessing properties from reference geometries, there's [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix) which is meant to perform such analysis. Some interesting stuff with [R](https://mgimond.github.io/tissot/)

Comment: perhaps better to use the official EPSG registry API (epsg.org)

Comment: @nmtoken  The EPSG registry doesn't store that information separately. Matifou, some projection names have included the information "conformal", "equal area", 'equidistant" but many do not.

Comment: @mkennedy, my bad for misreading the question, I was thinking of area (extent) over which the crs operates, and conversion properties etc

Answer (score 2):

"Alternatively, could I create polygons in long-lat, compute their area/distances etc using spherical geometry (S2), and then compare to the results obtained after projection using planar geometry? Would that be a valid approach to infer its property?"

Probably not. Projections may only preserve properties like scale along special lines, so you'd have to test over a wide region and then have some sort of heuristic to work out what sort of projection you have.

Much easier, I think, to construct a table of properties for each projection type, and look it up. You can get the projection type from `st_crs`:

```
> st_crs(27700)$proj
[1] "tmerc"
> st_crs(3857)$proj
[1] "merc"
> st_crs(3035)$proj
[1] "laea"
```

These three are a transverse Mercator, a (non-Transverse) Mercator, and a Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area.

The `proj` command line can tell you more about what projections it knows:

```
$ proj -lP
aea : Albers Equal Area
    Conic Sph&Ell
    lat_1= lat_2=
aeqd : Azimuthal Equidistant
    Azi, Sph&Ell
    lat_0 guam
... etc ...
```

Which shows that `aea` is Conic, `aeqd` is Azimuthal, etc. There's only a few types amongst the (for me) 162 projections that `proj` understands (Azimuthal, Cylindrical and Conical seems to cover most) so you could take that output and work out the projection properties for those and you're pretty much done...

Comment: thanks! Could you clarify your point against a data-driven method to infer the projection's property? How does preserving a property "only along special lines" prevent from inferring it? Are you concerned all properties would be rejected? Finally, what about the  Tissot's indicatrix? Thanks!!

Comment: How would you discover a map was an equidistant projection without somehow discovering its lines of equidistance? Yes you could compute the properties of Tissot's Inds at a large number of points on a map but that doesn't tell you all the properties you want.

Comment: @Spacedman I don't think OP is looking for cylindrical/conic/azimuthal. There are equal area, conformal, and equidistant conic projections, for example.